# How can I use wildcards to effectively filter on hierarchial data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, moodle

I am reporting on [Moodle's `mdl_course_categories`](https://moodleschema.zoola.io/tables/course_categories.html) table via the [configurable reports block](https://moodle.org/plugins/block_configurable_reports), which I have created a filter on the `path` column to filter the data I need. This `select` statement worked perfectly until the "Bananas" entry was created:

```sql
-- get the "Test Category" category and all categories that sit underneath it
select id, name, path from mdl_course_categories where path like '/2%'
```

```
| id  | name          | path |
|-----|---------------|------|
| 2   | Test Category | /2   |
| 3   | Apples        | /2/3 |
| 4   | Red Apples    | /2/4 |
| 5   | Green Apples  | /2/5 |
| 24  | Bananas       | /24  |
```

As you can see, "Bananas" appears in the results, which I don't want as it isn't a sub-category of "Test Category". I'm not the best at SQL, so I thought I could modify my usage of the `'%'` wildcard so that it will capture  `/2` and `/2/%` but exclude `/24` and similar entries that are created in the future:

```sql
-- get the "Test Category" category and all categories that sit underneath it
select id, name, path from mdl_course_categories where path like '/2%' 
   and path not like '/2%/'
```

However, this returns the exact same dataset as the first query. How can I fix this?

Intended result:

```
| id  | name          | path |
|-----|---------------|------|
| 2   | Test Category | /2   |
| 3   | Apples        | /2/3 |
| 4   | Red Apples    | /2/4 |
| 5   | Green Apples  | /2/5 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT id, name, path FROM mdl_course_categories WHERE (id = 2 OR path LIKE '/2/%')
```

I have put the conditions in brackets, as you often need to combine it with other AND conditions, which would go outside the brackets.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Unfortunately, the config reports block complains about not enough disk space for the temp file, which in my experience means that the dataset its trying to return is larger than what the database allows (there's about 1100 courses within this particular category tree). Any ideas why this extra AND causes it to overflow?

Comment: The query I posted simply lists a few details about the course categories found within a single category, it doesn't show any details about courses. If there is a massive tree of categories within the top-level category you selected, then that might be a problem, but that would be outside of the original question (I don't believe there is a more efficient way to undertake the query you requested, so you will need to find a different approach to the problem).

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
SELECT * FROM mdl_course_categories WHERE path LIKE '/2/%';
```